# manage_pages only a one fanpage

Tags: facebook, permissions, fan-page

I need to get permission from a single fanpage and not of all, I have seen applications that do, I wonder if anyone knows how to do it!

Is that possible to give 'manage_pages' permission only to one page? How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: No, as far as I know it’s a _all or nothing_ deal – the user can either give access to all of their pages, or not give the permission at all. And I have seen no app yet doing what you said – do you have any examples?

Comment: The only way I can see of doing this is having your own database that matches a uid to a page_id and ensuring that the UID only exists once in your table. Force the user to choose a single page (even though you can get access_tokens for all of them) I presume it's so you can prevent them from running an app on multiple pages if they only authorise one?